# wait t time before launch an action?

Tags: android

I actually had a multiautocompletetextview, where i call host after 3 characters to have a dynamic search list. 
But if the user put others characters, my code call host for each of them. So it must be very long.

Could I wait a moment (about 500 ms) before launching the action , in order to look if user do an action or not ? that's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a separeted thread. When the user entered the text you could create a thread, make it sleep for 500ms and when it will wake up check if the text typed is changed.

**EDIT**

Create a Handler

```
private Handler h = new Handler();
```

Create a runnable that makes your dynamic search

```
private Runnable myrunnable = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       ....
};
```

Then call your runnable in onTextChanged like

```
h.postDelayed(myrunnable, 500);
```

see [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for more options/informations

Make sure that your threads will access the memory in a consistent way!