# On click - starting another activity after a time

Tags: java, android

I need this button, to wait with proccesing to another activity (secondclas), for the time of the animation (out1). How to code it?

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
           image1.startAnimation(out1);
           Intent Intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), secondclass.class);
           startActivityForResult(Intent, 0);
       } 
   }) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Animation.AnimationListener().  You can implement the onAnimationEnd(...) method and launch the new activity there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) like this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            out1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Intent Intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), secondclass.class);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent, 0);
                }
            });
            image1.startAnimation(out1);
        } 
    }) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the animation time with out1.getDuration(). The intent can be started after that time using a delayed handler.

More details about how to start the delayed handler can be found here: [wait t time before launch an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801719/wait-t-time-before-launch-an-action)